# How to process multipart/mixed in C#

Tags: c#, http

Fiddler shows that server processed my request successfully. I get back a boundary-separated list of HTTP responses. But processing multipart/mixed response is new to me.

Based upon research, I tried the following:

```
httpResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

var content = new StreamContent(httpResp.GetResponseStream());

var streamProvider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();

var task = content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(streamProvider).ContinueWith(t =>
    {
        foreach (HttpContent item in streamProvider.Contents) {
           log.Debug("in foreach");
           partResStr = item.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
           log.DebugFormat("partResStr = {0}", partResStr);
        }
    });
```

But the logging on the foreach doesn't occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I did this, I had to set the `ContentType` of the `StreamContent`:

```
var streamContent = new StreamContent(stream);
streamContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentType);
var provider = streamContent.ReadAsMultipartAsync().Result;
```

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that was missing when staring at my code. And just verified that adding it made it work. Change was:

Comment: var content = new StreamContent(httpResp.GetResponseStream());
    content.Headers.Add("Content-Type", httpResp.ContentType); //added

Comment: One thing I'm still trying to clear up is are there any advantages/disadvantages when comparing these two approaches to getting insights

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/69999732748?fields=insights.metric(page_fan_adds_unique,page_fan_adds).since(2015-08-12).until(2015-08-13).period(day)

vs

https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/69999732748/insights/page_fan_adds_unique,page_fan_adds?period=day&since=2015-09-12&until=2015-09-13

I know that with the first that I could request additional non-insights fields. But if I'm just getting insights, is there really any difference?

Comment: @ChrisHarrington Did you post that comment in the right place? I don't think it's related to this question.